# no battery detected, empty power_supply and acpi directories

Tags: debian, battery, acpi, powermanager

there is no battery detected. there are no forums with the solution. I've edited grub to force acpi and i have nothing listed in proc/acpi/battery or /sys/class/power_supply. i have reinstalled with different distributions, releases, desktop environments, all with no success. kali 2018.1 (LXDE only) is the only kernel(4.14)/distro combination i could get both sound card and wireless card working. no battery detected on any distribution. if you could do me a solid and get past the word "kali" and focus more on the firmware that'd be awesome.

epik ell1401

i am aware of the quality of the laptop. thanks for any assistance.

Comment: This is a https://unix.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: Probably, but being as how I've searched and experimented for weeks to resolve this issue, I'm not going to pass a chance someone may see it here and not there.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435598/no-battery-detected-empty-power-supply-and-acpi-directories/435828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by replacing the intel_cht_int33fe.ko module from different distributions.

the intel_cht_int33fe.ko from lubuntu 17 (kernel 4.13) works fantastically. i also switched TYPEC_FUSB302, CHARGER_BQ24190,and BATTERY_MAX17042 from not set to loadable. it shows the percentage, meter, time remaining to charge/discharge. ErikF i thank you sir for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It would be good if you can submit a bug on kernel bugzilla if the issue is reproducible on vanilla kernels.